# Put elements from post php into an array and then in a table Mysql

Tags: php

I have tryed many things.. need simply to retriev values posted from another page put in array and then add the values to a table with unique name

```
<?php
$f1 = $_POST['f1'];

$f2 = $_POST['f2'];

$f3 = $_POST['f3'];

....

$f5 = $_POST['f100'];

$Array = array()

 for (i=0;i<100;i++){
 $Array = $f[i]
 }
```

then

```
 for(i=0;i<sizeof($Array);i++){
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `current stock` (ItemNumber, Stock)
           VALUES
          (Itam1, 'Array[i]' )";
  }

  ?>
```

Comment: `$_POST` is already an array. Is there anything else inside it, other than these `f[number]` fields?

Comment: `$f` doesn't exist. Not clear what that bit is about. As El_vanja said, $_POST is already an array. So `$Array = $_POST;` might be all you need? And then you wouldn't need $f because it's just an identical copy.

Comment: And it looks like the INSERT doesn't use the actual array value. However you should be using parameterised queries. So e.g. if you use mysqli for your database it would be something like `$sql = "INSERT INTO \`current stock\` (ItemNumber, Stock)            VALUES           ('Item1', ? )"; $stmt = $db->prepare($sql); $stmt->bind_param("s", $Array[$i]); $stmt->execute();   }`

Comment: no the variable $f1 have inside an only value.What is is that i am not able to make that variables... $f1 $f2 ... $f100 in an array programattically

Comment: You're not explaining it very well I'm afraid. As we said, $_POST is already an array. Not sure why you would need individual variables.

Comment: $_POST receive only one value inside it already. and need to put all $f variables inside an array

Comment: `$_POST receive only one value inside it`... You've shown 
$_POST['f1'], $_POST['f2'], $_POST['f3']. So that's not one value, that's 3 already, and they are all in the same array already. If you write `var_dump($_POST);` you'll see they are all in one array. You don't need to split them into $f1, $f2 etc.

Comment: ah okeythats cool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this ($_POST is an array allready, as mentioned by @EL_Vanja):

```
// Some random values, for demonstration...
$_POST['f1'] = 12;
$_POST['f2']  ="string";
$_POST['f3'] = 12.12;
$_POST['f100'] = rand(0,10);


$array = [];
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
 $array[$key] =$value;
 }
print("<pre>".print_r($array,true)."</pre>");
```

will printout:

```
<pre>
Array
(
    [f1] => 12
    [f2] => string
    [f3] => 12.12
    [f100] => 6
)
</pre>
```

And for the query part:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `current stock` (ItemNumber, Stock) VALUES ";
$lastElement = end($array);
$i = 1;
foreach($array as $arr){
    if($arr == $lastElement) {
        $separator = ";";
    } else {
         $separator = ",";
    }
    
    $sql .= "(Item".$i.", $arr)". $separator;
    $i++;

}
print_r($sql);
```

And the query will look like:

```
INSERT INTO `current stock` (ItemNumber, Stock) VALUES (Item1, 12),(Item2, string),(Item3, 12.12),(Item4, 7);
```